# Programmatically Execute an EventTrigger

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a control defined in Silverlight as follows:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="testHyperlink" Content="Test" FontWeight="Bold" Click="testHyperlink_Click">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
      <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility" TargetName="panel1"   
        Value="Collapsed" />
      <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility" TargetName="panel2" 
        Value="Visible" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger>
      <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility" TargetName="panel1" 
        Value="Visible" />
      <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility" TargetName="panel2" 
        Value="Collapsed" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

This hyperlink is part of a DataTemplate. That is the reason I'm using the triggers. When someone clicks the HyperlinkButton, an asynchronous process is fired. When the process has completed, I want to execute the second trigger. Essentially, I'm flipping the visibility of some content.

My question is, when my event is finished, how do I fire the second EventTrigger associated with the HyperlinkButton?

Answer (score 1):

It's incorrect using of Interactivity EventTriggers. Answering directly your question, you can do next (I'm writting that only because I coudn't write that it's impossible, but I'm ashamed for this solution):

create own action with public Invoke

```
    public class MyChangePropertyAction: ChangePropertyAction
    {
        public new void Invoke(object parameter)
        {
            base.Invoke(parameter);
        }
    }
```

Use it instead Interactivity ChangePropertyAction. Now you can get invoke action directly from code behind:

```
((MyChangePropertyAction)Interaction.GetTriggers(testHyperlink)[1]).Invoke(parameter);
```

**But**, I believe that you can simply use MVVM approach and do next:

- create bool property IsBusy with property changed notification in view model;
- bind it to your "panel1" Visibility property via BooleanToVisibility converter;
- bind command DoServiceCall from view model to "testHyperlink" Command property;
- and in view model make service calls and change IsBusy property to true or false depending on should you display panel or not.

Good luck